# How do I create this material in cycles (2.79)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

This question is a repost: I wanted to know how I could make the material shown on the characters shown here:

[image]

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [ibtimes.com](https://s1.ibtimes.com/sites/www.ibtimes.com/files/styles/lg/public/2016/08/16/five-nights-freddys-baby.jpg))</sub>

[image]

Now let me explain:

I am trying to make a fan game with similar aesthetics to the ones in this game, FNAF: Sister Location, where the character screenshots were taken from. For months now, I've been trying to recreate the materials on the characters. What materials, you ask? Basically, all of them that you can see. You may be thinking that I should limit this question to one material, but the thing is, all of them are the same, despite different colors and/or normal maps. Now, you might also want more information on these materials. From my analysis, they're super reflective and metallic in little to no light. However, their specular in the brighter light makes it seem almost like a leathery material. For example, if you view the image with the snouted white-and-pink character gripping a disco ball looking microphone, you can see what I'm talking about. Around the bottom of his lower jaw, it is super reflective, but where the specular is, there is little to no reflection at all.

Keep in mind that I have researched all the videos that are relevant to this, but none provided an accurate node setup. How do I create this in cycles?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the materials have anything particular, it looks like normal plastic, like a *Diffuse* mixed with a *Glossy*, with various values, plus perhaps *Fresnel* and *SSS*. It seems to me that what you think comes from the material may actually comes from the work with lighting, so maybe you should dig that aspect?

[image]